# Windows 8 remote desktop file copying

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-8

I do not seem to be able to copy a file through the Windows 8 Remote Desktop Connection.

Is there a way to make this happen? Do I have to install the 'old' remote desktop program to do this?

Apparently, in the old remote desktop program, you could even set it up to mount my local computer's HDDs on the remote server for the duration of the RDP-Session. Maybe this could still work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two distinct Remote Desktop apps available from Microsoft for Windows 8. The desktop version of the app has all the same features as the Windows 7 version (as well as [significant behind-the-scenes enhancements](https://web.archive.org/web/20150930113540/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2012/06/13/remote-desktop-services-what-s-new-in-windows-server-2012-release-candidate.aspx)) and should be able to copy/paste files over the connection, as well as map a drive to a shared folder or mount the drives on either end, just like in Windows 7.

The is also an RT version of the app. This version has the same file system restrictions as other Modern UI style apps, and so it is much more limited for things it can do on the file system. This app was built-in for the Consumer and Release Preview versions of Windows 8, but now must be downloaded from the Windows Store.

Additionally, if you have a Windows RT tablet, you can still access the full desktop RDP client! Just hit `Windows Key` + `R`, and then type `mstsc` into the box that opens, and you'll get the full RDP client.

Comment: Many of the limitations is likely because of its a first release of the application itself.  Microsoft has proven its able to provide fully functional Modern UI applications ( i.e. Skype ) quickly.

Comment: I didn't see that the 'old' RDP was still around on win 8. I will use that one until they maybe update the RT app, then, although I liked being able to switch between my desktop and the remote machine using the top left corner..

Answer (score 2):

On my Windows 8 computer, `mstsc.exe` still has the option to map drives (check the `More` button under the `Local Resources` tab).

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Answer (score 1):

The old Remote Desktop is still available in Windows 8 but is hidden!!!
You have to press windows+q 
Now type remote and you will find the old application along with the tablet app. 
You can pin the full application in you task bar. 
I believe strongly that Microsoft should consider launching a real desktop version of Windows 8.